# Hadoop Distributed Cache error message interpretation

Tags: hadoop, distributed-cache

I'm trying to place 3 files in the Distributed Cache.

I place one of them programmatically, using:

```
  DistributedCache.addLocalFiles(conf, "local/path/to/file");
```

And I also place 2 other files using the `-files` option.

When running locally, in standalone mode, everything works fine.

When trying to run it in pseudo-distributed mode, I get this error and I don't understand its meaning. I googled for it but with no success.

```
  Distributed cache entry arrays have different lengths
```

Does anyone know what it means and how it could be solved ?

Comment: Where is the first line of code? What class?

Comment: In the driver class ... the class containing the main .. so on the JobClient side if this is what you ask.

Comment: And the files are files on the client machine ... not in the HDFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stemmed from the fact that I was adding to the cache local files.

Instead I moved those files to the HDFS and added the HDFS version to the DistributedCache. It worked!